# AngularJS: Setting value of form field to various object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple AngularJS dynamic form that is bound by ng-model to a property modelParams.value.  Each form field displays the value of modelParams.value However, I would like to have a button called "Default" that sets the values of all of the form fields to some other property in this associative array such as modelParams.defaultValue, or modelParams.oldValue.  I assume that once the "Default" button is pressed this would override the value of ng-model="modelParams.value".

Here is the form:

```
<form name="modelParamsForm">                   
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="modelParam in modelParams">
        <div class="row">
         //INPUT FORM FIELDS
         <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" required ng-
         model="modelParam.value" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-
        click="updateModelParams(modelParams, modelParamsForm)">
    </button>
    //DEFAULT BUTTON
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-
     click="default()">Default</button>         
</form>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"model":"MAF","paramname":"CascDefaultSpreadOverride","minvalue":"0","maxvalue":"100","description":"The defaault repo spread override to use for CASC positions.","defaultvalue":1.0,"value":1.0,"datatype":"FLOAT"},{"model":"MAF","paramname":"DefaultLotSize","minvalue":"1","maxvalue":"1000","description":"The minimum lot size that must be met for a collateral allocation.","defaultvalue":1.0,"value":1.0,"datatype":"INTEGER"},{"model":"MAF","paramname":"HtbColdHaircut","minvalue":"0","maxvalue":"100","description":"The haircut to apply to positions with a Cold HTB category.","defaultvalue":0.1,"value":0.1,"datatype":"FLOAT"},{"model":"MAF","paramname":"HtbExtraHotHaircut","minvalue":"0","maxvalue":"100","description":"The haircut to apply to positions with a Extra-Hot HTB category.","defaultvalue":0.9,"value":0.9,"datatype":"FLOAT"},]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.field = 'value';

$scope.change = function() {
  $scope.field = 'oldValue';
}


...ng repeat blabla
<input ng-model="modelParam[field]"/>
...
<button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
```

EDIT: Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zy94an54/

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit.  At this point I am getting each object in modelParams via ng-repeat.  I guess you want me to set modelParam.value to $scope.field and then modelParam.otherValue to 'old value' in the change() method...?  Does that mean I have to also have to loop over modelParams array in my controller?

Comment: What I want you to do is use some variable as index to a modelParam property. Check the jsFiddle, it should be clearer

Comment: Oh, that worked, at least with changing the values in the form.  However, the 'oldvalues' that populate the form once we click Default are not updating the database.  That is to say, they appear in the form but once you call  click="updateModelParams(modelParams, modelParamsForm)" it is as if those values are not actually there...

Comment: Check this fiddle. Try changing an input, see the variable being updated: http://jsfiddle.net/8w91m137/

Comment: Oh no, my mistake!  Your code works as intended!  But, what I am trying to do is populate the form fields with 'oldvalue' with change() then on update() set 'oldvalue' as 'value' in the object.  In other words, I am trying to restore the object to its 'oldvalue' state.  How foolish of me I did not explain this!  Now it is two-way binding 'oldvalue' in view and model, but I need to update 'value' param with 'oldvalue'.  I hope I am making more sense now...

Comment: Then your change function doesnt need to change the ng-model reference. It needs to replace value with oldValue. ng-model reference will remain being value, only that now it will have oldValue's value. Read this 3 times out loud =P

Comment: Ok so my ng-model remains ng-model[value], but my change() method should not replace the reference of $scope.field = value to 'oldvalue' but it should make 'value' have the value of 'oldvalue'...hmmm.  But if I am not changing the reference of the $scope.field = value then how would I set it to oldvalue ?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n28zLog0/1/  We are now moving away from your original question

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Of course you would have to iterate though the array of objects to get value prop and change it to oldval.  You must be a genius.